# How does the reinterpret_cast work?

Tags: c++, byte, binaryfiles, reinterpret-cast

I'm wondering how does reinterpret_cast work behind the scenes. I'm learning about it from a book, but i just don't get it.
E.g. suppose i have the following part of code:

```
int a = 255;
char *pChar = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a);
```

or

```
std::string str = "Hello";
char *pChar = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&str);
```

What will pChar pointed to in both examples, why i can't see anything when i try to print their contents, and of course how does reinterpret_cast work?

**Edit:**
I know reinterpret_cast is pretty dangerous to use, and only want to use it to write bytes directly into a binary file from a block of memory.
What i don't understand is that when i have an

```
int a = 255; (00 00 00 FF in memory)
```

and i want to treat the variable `a` as a series of bytes, char* :

```
char *pChar = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a);
```

Will pChar point to the individual bytes of variable `a` (00 00 00 FF)?

So when i want to write into a binary file what the `pChar` pointed to:

```
a_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
```

It writes the individual bytes of variable `a`, right?

Comment: The C++ compiler and run-time library will treat any `char*` as a C-style null-terminated byte string. If it actually *isn't* that, then you can't print (or otherwise treat) it as such.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a)` tells the compiler "we both know that `&a` isn't a `char*`, but let's pretend that it is."

Comment: As someone learning C++ `reinterpret_cast` should be avoided.  Learning about it if fine; there are however relatively few places you can use this cast in your code without creating undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude umm, wat?!  Whilst the C standard library's string functions will indeed usually take `char *` parameters which are expected to contain a `NUL` terminated string, that is _not_ intrinsic to the `char *` type itself, and nor does the compiler make that assumption, except when parsing string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What will pChar pointed to in both examples?

They will point to the first char of the memory where these variables are reside.

> why i can't see anything when i try to print their contents

You maybe do it in a wrong way. You cannot print them as a null terminated string (for example, `a`'s internal representation contains 0, which will be treated as a terminating zero).

You can print them like this:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<sizeof(int); i++) {
    printf("%02x ", pChar[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

This will print the character values of `a` in hexadecimal. This way, you'll see `ff 00 00 00` (assuming that you're on a little endian machine).

You can do the same with `std::string`. You'll see the memory representation of `std::string`.

(You can print contents as char with "%c". If you redirect stdout to a file, you'll see the internal representation of the variable in the file.

> and of course how does reinterpret_cast work?

It just reinterprets its parameter, pretending that it has another type. No runtime costs involved (note: this explanation is highly simplified).

> Will pChar point to the individual bytes of variable a (00 00 00 FF)?

Yes, assuming that char is a byte, and you're on a big endian machine.

> It writes the individual bytes of variable a, right

Yes, but presumably you can do the same without any reinterpret_cast too, it is not needed here (supposing that `a_file.write`'s first argument is a `void *`)

Answer (score 6):

It does not do anything at runtime. [Cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

> Unlike static_cast, but like const_cast, the reinterpret_cast
>   expression does not compile to any CPU instructions. It is purely a
>   compiler directive which instructs the compiler to treat the sequence
>   of bits (object representation) of expression as if it had the type
>   new_type.

Both your conversions are pretty dangerous, because the first points the pointer to an int, which will likely be represented as `00 00 00 FF` in memory, thus not printing anything, because 00 == '\0', which is the end-of-string char. This assumes you are on a big-endian machine. If this was an `int` that filled all bytes with non-zero values, you would read indefinitely past the end of that location.

The second tells the compiler to treat the location where the `string` resides as `char*`, which is no the starting address of the actual string-content, but an implementation defined struct, which likley holds the size, capacity and pointer variables or a representation of the string for the small-string optmization. Since the size and capacity are typically 64-bit wide, and the size and capacity are probably both smaller than 2^32, you probably run into a zero-byte, thus printing nothing. Once again, if there is no accidental zero-byte, your read past the end indefinitely.

**To address OP's Edit:**

According to Section 5 of the linked cpp-reference site

> Any pointer to object of type T1 can be converted to pointer to object
>   of another type cv T2. This is exactly equivalent to static_cast(static_cast(expression)) (which implies that if T2's
>   alignment requirement is not stricter than T1's, the value of the
>   pointer does not change and conversion of the resulting pointer back
>   to its original type yields the original value). In any case, the
>   resulting pointer may only be dereferenced safely if allowed by the
>   type aliasing rules (see below)

conferred with below:

> When a pointer or reference to object whose dynamic type is
>   DynamicType is reinterpret_cast (or C-style cast) to a pointer or
>   reference to object of a different type AliasedType, the cast always
>   succeeds, but the resulting pointer or reference may only be used to
>   access the object if one of the following is true: ...
>
> AliasedType is char, unsigned char, or std::byte: this permits
>   examination of the object representation of any object as an array of
>   bytes. ...

, the pointer should point to the address where `a` started.

Comment: SBO strings could reuse size and/or capacity fields as part of the string itself.  But it is true that a SBO string is going to store a null somewhere in itself, so that doesn't matter much.  On the other hand, a string could be implemented as 3 pointers instead of a pointer, size and capacity.

Comment: Yeah, I left it at a "likely" there because I am not sure what the current implementations are. There is at least one possible implementation I heard of, which stores up to 23 bytes in the 24 bytes of `size, pointer, cap`, which reuses the fact that the last byte becoming zero as cap also doubles as terminating '\0'. I think all the bytes could be non-zero in that special case because one bit from the first byte is used to distinguish small string or not, and at `size == 22`, all bytes should be non-zero.

Comment: SBO must have a null terminator, because `c_str()` is `const` and returns a null terminated string.  That leaves the case where it isn't a SBO.

Comment: Yeah right, since at the `max-size - 1` the byte before the cap-byte is still a zero-byte. I think this talk elaborates on this optimization in detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPR8h4-qZdk